# Jquery-Mobile: How to get the text of the date box using ID

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

I am new to Jquery-Mobile date box. I want to get the text from the date field using the ID and set that text in the table. But I am not getting it. Please, can anybody help me?

```
code
<div data-role="page" id="Goal_Weight_Screen">

   <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >          
        <h1>Goal Count</h1> 
   </div>

    <div data-role="content">                 
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="mydate">Choose Start Date</label>
        <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox"
               data-options='{"mode": "datebox","disableManualInput": true}'> 
      </div>           
      <a href="#Calorie_Tracker" data-role="button">Submit</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="Calorie_Tracker">    

   <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" >           
        <h1>Calorie</h1> 
   </div>   
    <div data-role="content" id="table">                        
            <table id="calorie_table" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Food</th>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td id="date1">'+$('#mydate').val()+'</td>
                    <td id="FI_1"></td>                     
                </tr>       

            </table>            
    </div>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write a `<script>` tag and use the JQuery-Mobile method `pageshow`. Try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#Calorie_Tracker').live('pageshow', function(event, ui){
    $('#date1').val($('#mydate').val());
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You can also try `pageinit` event instead of `pageshow`. Check the documentation [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfZC/1/). It gives me some weird error but you can see an alert with the date. I hop it will work in you application.